# featured image is not showing

Tags: post-thumbnails

i have a problem with my website my feature images are not shown
i have uploaded it as set as featured image
but after so many tries there is no way to show the feature image please help me

Answer (score 1):

You need to call it in your theme.
open your theme index.php or better if you have loop.php and [inside the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)
add

```
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
  the_post_thumbnail();
} 
?>
```

Hope This helps.